# Can I use any other app instead of Expo to run react native app?

Tags: react-native

Can I use any other app instead of Expo to run react native app?
Expo is not compatible with my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the way suggested in the react-native docs [under using a real device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#using-a-real-device). You'll need `adb` installed, then just enable USB debugging on your phone and plug it in. Run `react-native run-android` in the command line to send your program to your phone.

Note that these steps may differ depending on how far you've followed to the directions for either expo or react-native.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.